# LINQ vs SQL while working with RDBMS

Tags: sql, linq

Can I absolutely abandon SQL if I choose LINQ?

If Yes, then, Should I absolutely abandon SQL if I choose LINQ?

After making a connection to RDBMS using DataContext-class, do I actually need SQL?

Comment: You are confused. LINQ is the set of language features.

Are you refering to LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only for the most simple cases, and no.  Respectively.

Linq is certainly awesome, but I don't know why you'd intentionally abandon SQL.  Linq2SQL's translations are pretty good, but sometimes, for an extra hairy report or something, there's no substitute for writing a stored procedure yourself.

Comment: +1 exactly - Linq-to-SQL is great - for 90% of the cases. For the remaining cases, you still need to know SQL and use SQL.

Comment: I see your update, but I don't know what it means.  Do you need SQL for what?

Comment: As I tried to say in my answer, then yes, you still need SQL.  Linq2SQL can not do everything SQL can, so that means you still need sql.